# How to send image id as function parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So i have this function:

```
function toggle()
{
  var Blur=document.getElementById('blur');
  Blur.classList.toggle('active');
  var PopUp=document.getElementById('PopUp');
  PopUp.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

which when you click an image opens a preview for that image. Instead of creating n functions for n photos on my website is there any way to send an image id as parameter?
I'm thinking something like:

```
function toggle(IdParameter)
{
  var Blur=document.getElementById('blur');
  Blur.classList.toggle('active');
  var PopUp=document.getElementById('IdParameter');
  PopUp.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Comment: You are passing a string literal to `getElementById('IdParameter')` instead of the function argument variable `getElementById(dParameter)` ... note no quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use "this" and paste image as element to the function .
Then you can get what you need from the image: src, alt, id, class..

```js
function myFunction(e){
console.log(e.src)

}
```

```html
 <img src="img_1.jpg" alt="image1" onclick="myFunction(this);">
 <img src="img_2.jpg" alt="image2" onclick="myFunction(this);">
```